# Weird foreground color issue with Cmder + PowerShell Core

Tags: powershell, cmder

Out of the box, running PowerShell with Cmder sets the foreground color to white:

[image]

Today I installed PowerShell Core and created a new Cmder task exactly like the default 'PowerShell as Admin task', but points to `pwsh.exe` instead of `Powershell.exe`:

`*C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -NoExit -Command "Invoke-Expression '. ''%ConEmuDir%\..\profile.ps1'''"`

For reasons I don't understand, the foreground color for the PowerShell Core window is green:

[image]

While trying to understand why, I spent some time fiddling with the following block of code contained in [`\vendor\profile.ps1`](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/blob/master/vendor/profile.ps1#L106-L109):

`[ScriptBlock]$CmderPrompt = {
  $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "White"
  Write-Host $pwd.ProviderPath -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
  checkGit($pwd.ProviderPath)
}`

Here's where it gets weird. If I change that `Write-Host` statement to use `-ForegroundColor White` instead of `Green`, the foreground color remains permanently white. If I change it to `Red`, the foreground color remains permanently red. Even weirder: If I leave the original `Write-Host` statement alone (using the original `Green` color), but add an additional `Write-Host` statement above it without a `Foregroundcolor` parameter, the foreground color remains white. It's as though a `Write-Host` statement is required in order to maintain the state of `$Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor`.

Anyone else experiencing this oddity? Am I missing something stupid?

I tried this with Cmder 1.3.5 and 1.3.6 - same result.

---

### Additional Examples:

#### Results in `white` foreground color:

`[ScriptBlock]$CmderPrompt = {
  $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "White"
  Write-Host $pwd.ProviderPath -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor White
  checkGit($pwd.ProviderPath)
}`

#### Also results in `white` foreground color:

`[ScriptBlock]$CmderPrompt = {
  $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "White"
  Write-Host "blah"
  Write-Host $pwd.ProviderPath -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
  checkGit($pwd.ProviderPath)
}`

#### Results in `red` foreground color:

`[ScriptBlock]$CmderPrompt = {
  $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "White"
  Write-Host "blah" -ForegroundColor Red
  Write-Host $pwd.ProviderPath -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
  checkGit($pwd.ProviderPath)
}`

Comment: Report this to cmder authors

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. I use a portable version of cmder on two different computers. On both of them, I use pwsh 6.1.0, but weirdly enough only one of them has this foreground color issue.

Comment: Note that I did [open an issue about this](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1899) on the Cmder github repo.

Comment: This is a problem for me as of the Windows 10 v1809 update. Effecting two separate machines.

Comment: Yeah, I *just* updated to the latest Windows 10 and now this is an issue with both PS Core and PS 5.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment to the question, I am also experiencing this issue. I did not exactly find out why this is happening, but I have found a workaround.

The OP inspired me to poke around with `Write-Host` as well, so I've come up with this:

```
# File "$env:CMDER_ROOT\config\user-profile.ps1"
# I copy-pasted this from "$env:CMDER_ROOT\vendor\profile.ps1" and added the `b line.
[ScriptBlock]$CmderPrompt = {
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "White"

    # Workaround to make above line apply the "White" foreground color.
    # Seems like you have to print _something_ before using Write-Host with -ForegroundColor.
    # Note: Empty string "" doesn't work.
    Write-Host "`r" -NoNewline

    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host $pwd.ProviderPath -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host (checkGit($pwd.ProviderPath)) -NoNewLine 
}
```

This works for me because I know that the cursor is at the beginning of a line at that point, so `r doens't do anything. Not pretty but it's a quick fix that works. I hope it does for others, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simpler workaround that will work until a known fix is made.

1. Open the default cmd session.
2. write `powershell` command.

Now you are in powershell but with all the default colors of cmd. Should be a great/easy solution if you need to open 2 split tabs. If you are lazy to write the powershell command, just create another cmd session with a start-up with the `powershell` command.